# Shade part of an R plot

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to make a plot in R that has a portion of the plot grey to emphasize this area.  Unlike other examples, I don't want to color an area under a plot, but instead color an area on a plot starting at one area and going to the end of the graph.  When I try to use rect() or polygon() it obscures the plots I want to emphasize.

For example:

```
x_mean <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
y_mean <- c(1, 1, 1, 1)

y_max <- c(4, 4, 4, 4)
y_min <- c(-4, -4, -4, -4)


x_shade <- c(2, 3, 4)

y_max_shade <- c(4, 4, 4)
y_min_shade <- c(-4, -4, -4)

plot(x=rep(x_mean, 3), y=c(y_mean, y_max, y_min), bty='n', type="n" )
arrows(x0=x_mean, y0=y_min, x1=x_mean, y1=y_max, length=0)
points( x=x_mean, y=y_mean, pch=16)
```

This will plot 4 lines on the graph.  How do I draw a grey box in the background from the 2nd line to the end of the plot?

Comment: R graphics uses a pen+paper model, which means objects drawn later are drawn _on top of_ earlier objects. Try plotting with `rect()` first, and then drawing the points and lines you want.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just so that you're left with more than just a comment, here's a possible solution:

```
plot(x=rep(x_mean, 3), y=c(y_mean, y_max, y_min), bty='n', type="n" )
rect(2,-4,4,4,col = rgb(0.5,0.5,0.5,1/4))
arrows(x0=x_mean, y0=y_min, x1=x_mean, y1=y_max, length=0)
points( x=x_mean, y=y_mean, pch=16)
```

[image]

Note that I also demonstrated how to use alpha blending in the color specification (using `rgb`). This can also be useful for this sort of thing. Try moving the `rect` line to the end, and notice that the results still look ok, because the fill color is partially transparent.

Answer (score 2):

I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23351752/shading-area-between-two-lines-in-r) to be pretty great for shading background parts of R.

Some context:

`panel.first = rect(c(1,7), -1e6, c(3,10), 1e6, col='green', border=NA)`

The first two arguments `c(1,7)` are the starting values for the shaded rectangle, and following arguments `c(3,10)` are where the shading ends. This creates a shaded region from 1-3 and 7-10.