# shading area between two lines in r

Tags: r, plot

For example if i need to shade two area in plot

```
x<-rep(1:10)
plot(x,type="h")
```

I need as an example shade the area from 1 to 3 and from 7 to 10,

I use this commands but it omitted the lines of plot.

```
usr <- par('usr')
rect(1, usr[3], 3, usr[4], col='green')
```

Comment: you could redraw the lines after you draw the rectangle (`lines(x,type="h")`); you might also want to use `border=NA` in your `rect()` call to suppress the edges.

Comment: you could use `rect(1, usr[3], 3, usr[4], col="#00FF0070")` instead, since "#00FF00" is green and the last two correspond to transparency, 00 being fully transparent and FF opaque

Comment: good, do you know any different colour,

Comment: I know all the colors! just scroll down and copy the function `tcol` from here (line 489 it starts) https://github.com/raredd/rawr/blob/master/R/utils.R

Comment: Could a vertical `abline` be used here, provided it stops at the height of `x`?

Comment: Alternatively, use `plot(x, type="h", lwd=3)`.

Comment: Note you can convert any of the named colours (see `colors()`) to hex with `do.call(rgb, c(list(t(col2rgb('tomato'))), max=255))`. Replace `tomato` with your favourite colour.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can get what you want by using the little-known `panel.first=` argument to `plot.default()`:

```
plot(x,type="h", 
     panel.first = {
         usr <- par('usr')
         rect(c(1,7), usr[3], c(3,10), usr[4], col='green', border=NA)
     })
```

Or, to avoid any mucking around with `par('usr')` values, just do:

```
plot(x, type="h", 
     panel.first = rect(c(1,7), -1e6, c(3,10), 1e6, col='green', border=NA))
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Fantastic! So many times I've plotted with `type='n'` in order to plot shading etc. and subsequently using `lines` or `points`. This is one to remember. I never thought to look under `?plot.default` hence never came across this.

Comment: @jbaums Very glad to hear you like it. I only took the time to answer with the hope that someone else would find it useful, so it's esp. nice to hear that someone did!

Answer (score 5):

See ?polygon:

```
polygon( x = c(1,1,3,3,1), y=c( usr[1], x[1], x[3], usr[1], usr[1]) ,col="red")

> polygon( x = c(1,1,3,3,1), y=c( usr[1], x[1], x[3], usr[1], usr[1]) ,col="red")
> polygon( x = c(7,7,10,10,7), y=c( usr[2], x[7], x[10], usr[1], usr[1]) ,col="red")
```

I chose to close the polygon but seem I remember you can get it to self-close.

[image]

Comment: Yup, from the `help(polygon)`: *It is assumed that the polygon is to be closed by joining the last point to the first point.*

Comment: I don't think this actually answers the OP's question (they are using `rect()` successfully), which has to do with obscuring the plot behind the polygon/rectangle.

Comment: The OP was asking for "shade the area from 1 to 3 and from 7 to 10" which I would argue is really quite ambiguous as to what was really desired. I took it to mean the irregular polygon that I demonstrated how to draw. Apparently you and two others believed it was something different. I cannot really comment with authority because the mind-reading dongle for my network interface seem to be on the fritz.